# handling backpress event in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to handled the backpress button in windows phone 8.1 app.I want whenever backpress is pressed navigate to previous page but when backpress is pressed at the second page(after the mainpage) i want the app to exit or asked to exit.
i am using this code to navigate

```
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed +=             HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,      Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. It works for me.

private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            e.Handled = true;

```
        var curpage = rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType.FullName;
            if(curpage=="your page name where you want to show dialog")
            { 
            var msg = new MessageDialog("Sure to Exit?");
            var okBtn = new UICommand("OK");
            var cancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel");
            msg.Commands.Add(okBtn);
            msg.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);
            IUICommand result = await msg.ShowAsync(); 
            if (result != null && result.Label == "OK")
            {
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        }
            else
            {
                if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
                {
                    rootFrame.GoBack();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding to your quesiton is everytime when user what to navigate back to the first page by pressing back button, you want to exit the app. If so, what we need to do is in the first page's OnNavigatedFrom event to check if the NavigationMode is Back. Try the following code:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            App.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the history of the first navigated page, you can remove it from BackStack, and the second page is considered as first one. Just put this on your mainpage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.First());
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```